# liftM in ghci: why is there such difference?

Tags: haskell, monads, ghci, lifting

When I define such functions inside ghci:

```
> :m Control.Monad
> let f n = n+1
> let g = liftM f
```

they work well:

```
> g $ Just 2
> Just 3
> g $ [1,2]
> [2,3]
```

But when I define the same functions in file (probl.hs):

```
 import Control.Monad

 f :: Integer -> Integer
 f n = n + 2

 g = liftM f
```

and then run this file via ghci:

```
 ghci probl.hs
```

I got such message:

```
probl.hs:6:5: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `m0' arising from a use of `liftM'
      prevents the constraint `(Monad m0)' from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        g :: m0 Integer -> m0 Integer (bound at probl.hs:6:1)
...
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Why is there such difference? And how to solve problem with second situation (I want the same behavior like in first one)?

Comment: I can see now, that answer belongs to the topic of Monomorphism Restriction, but point of question was about behaviour of ghci and liftM inside it. I think it is little different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being hit by the dreaded Monomorphism Restriction! It is an unintuitive rule that is turned off in GHCi, but on when you compile. Use a type signature (recommended), or `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` to disable it. Basically, it sometimes makes expressions without type signatures less polymorphic than you would expect.

[Further reading](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction)